# Disable Joomla virtuemart from allowing users to register using same email id

Tags: php, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I'm developing an **eCommerce** site using `Joomla 3.3` and `Virtuemart 3`, but for some reason, uniqueness of the **emailID** is not checked.

*No alert/validation error* is shown when a user try to register with already registered email id. Also, no alert message is displayed if the username entered by a user is already registered.

I want to disable this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What steps you have tried?

Comment: I have done some research, but read as this is an added advantage of joomla. even tried this, I added
function checkEmail() {
var email = document.getElementById('email_field');
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
alert('Please insert correct e-mail address.');
email.focus;
return false;
}
}

Comment: Please check this link, tried this also https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=119490.0

Comment: Hi, did you get to solve your problem?

If your problem is solved, can you please give me some details, since i'm stuck with a similar problem.